# How to disable multitouch zooming on my mobile web page?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, safari, mobile-safari

I would like to disable multitouch on my mobile web site, so that they can't zoom it on Mobile Safari, how can I do so?

Comment: Why the #%@$ would you want to do that?  I can't read your site if I can't zoom.

Comment: @stephen mobile sites, as i know on my android, fits perfectly with my screen and are not zoomable as i know

Comment: @Luke they *could* be zoomable, if it wasn't prevented. I have poor vision, I either need to zoom or get out a magnifying glass to use my iTouch.  I'm so tired of sites with tiny text and/or light-grey-on-white text (#666 is the text color of the beast) but I can fix those with my browser extensions. It's not so easy on a mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to stop the users from zooming if they want to (it seems right up there with disabling right-click), but it can be done. To stop zooming, use the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag):

```
<meta name="viewport" 
 content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

[Another way with the viewport meta tag](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html):

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = 320, 
                                   initial-scale = 2.3, 
                                   user-scalable = no">
```